# combining similar key/value pair into an array

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if I can combine multiple objects based on a given id into an array of an object? Hopefully I can explain this better below:

trying to have an output of each index item of carCollection to be like this:

```
[
  {
    brand: 'Porsche',
    model: ['Cayenne', 'Macan'],
    id: 1
  },
  {
    brand: 'BMW',
    model: ['M4','M3'],
    id: 3
  }
]
```

But the code below duplicates `id:1` car brand Porsche into the `carCollection`:

```
[
  {
    brand: 'Porsche',
    model: ['Cayenne'],
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    brand: 'Porsche',
    model: ['Macan'],
    id: 1
  }
]
```

```
let cars = {
    brands: [ {name:'Porsche', id:1}, {name:'Mercedes-Benz', id:2},{name:'BMW', id:3},],
    models: [  {name:'Cayenne', id:1}, {name:'C45', id:2}, {name:'M4', id:3}, {name:'M3', id:3}, {name:'Macan', id:1}]
}

// empty array
let carCollection = []

let { brands, models } = cars;


function carMatcher(brands, models){

    for(let brand of brands){
 
        for(let model of models){
            const carObject = {
                brand: '',
                model: [],
                id: 0
            }

           if(model.id === brand.id){
                    carObject.brand = brand.name
                    carObject.model.push(model.name)
                    carObject.id = brand.id
                    carCollection.push(carObject)
                
            } 
        }

    } 

}

carMatcher(brands, models)
```

Comment: And what if there are two cars of the same brand but with different ID or vice versa? Or is this impossible?

Comment: i would like to know too haha. its a challenge for myself and is definitely a case to write about BUT... i would think the different id would be a human error when inputting into a database FZs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
let cars = {
  brands: [
    { name: "Porsche", id: 1 },
    { name: "Mercedes-Benz", id: 2 },
    { name: "BMW", id: 3 },
  ],
  models: [
    { name: "Cayenne", id: 1 },
    { name: "C45", id: 2 },
    { name: "M4", id: 3 },
    { name: "M3", id: 3 },
    { name: "Macan", id: 1 },
  ],
};

const dict = new Map();

cars.brands.forEach(({ name, id }) => {
  dict.set(id, { brand: name, id, model: [] });
});

cars.models.forEach(({ name, id }) => {
  if (dict.has(id)) dict.get(id).model.push(name);
});

const result = [...dict.values()];
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**EDIT: Simpler version**

```js
let cars = {
  brands: [
    { name: "Porsche", id: 1 },
    { name: "Mercedes-Benz", id: 2 },
    { name: "BMW", id: 3 },
  ],
  models: [
    { name: "Cayenne", id: 1 },
    { name: "C45", id: 2 },
    { name: "M4", id: 3 },
    { name: "M3", id: 3 },
    { name: "Macan", id: 1 },
  ],
};

let dict = {},
  result = [];

for (let val of cars.brands) {
  dict[val.id] = {
    brand: val.name,
    id: val.id,
    model: [],
  };
}

for (let val of cars.models) {
  const id = val.id;
  const name = val.name;

  const objInDict = dict[id];
  if (objInDict) {
    objInDict.model.push(name);
  }
}

for (let key in dict) {
  result.push(dict[key]);
}

console.log(result);
```

**Simplest**

```js
let cars = {
  brands: [
    { name: "Porsche", id: 1 },
    { name: "Mercedes-Benz", id: 2 },
    { name: "BMW", id: 3 },
  ],
  models: [
    { name: "Cayenne", id: 1 },
    { name: "C45", id: 2 },
    { name: "M4", id: 3 },
    { name: "M3", id: 3 },
    { name: "Macan", id: 1 },
  ],
};

let result = [];
const { brands, models } = cars;

for (let brand of brands) {
  const { name, id } = brand;
  const newObj = { brand: name, id, model: [] };

  for (let model of models) {
    const { name, id } = model;
    if (newObj.id === id) {
      newObj.model.push(name);
    }
  }

  result.push(newObj);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: interestingg! Thank you decpk. If I were to stick it to my "old-fashioned" way, would it still be possible? I guess my current knowledge is lackluster =[ .  I think I made this project more of a challenge to myself and not so much of a deliverable product.

Comment: @JasonTodd I've added the simple version. Hope this is what you need. If it is not then please feel free to comment on what is in the code that is not so clear to you. Happy to assist.

Comment: @JasonTodd I've added two versions. I think the last one is the one that you want.

Comment: you are literally amazing!!! Thank you so much - love to see many ways to approach it.. one of my instructor at bootcamp says there are nearly unlimited ways of approach and you just made a great example of that haha